# custom loss - keras

Tags: keras, loss

The following two models/compilations behave differently:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

optimizer = Adam(lr=5e-3)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And:

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=5e-3)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "differently'?

Comment: When I observe the training, I see different numbers for loss (and accuracy). Really different, the custom loss doen't work while the out of the factory loss does.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. Both are producing exactly same output. I used `Keras 2.2.4.1` with `MxNet 1.5.0` (CPU version) backend on Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3. What tools are you using and what difference are you observing?

Comment: I'm using a mac, with Python 3, and Jupyter notebook. My target is multi label (117 binaries).

Comment: @Oren are you using your data in the same shuffled way. Also, are you seeding your network so that random initialisations are exactly same? There can be a lot of different things that induce randomness in neural nets.

Comment: @Anakin the same data, no seed, but ran several times and see the same phenomena.

Comment: Check once with seed as well. And how big a difference are we talking about here? Can you show some results?

Comment: The good case:     Train on 10815 samples, validate on 4636 samples
Epoch 1/10
 9408/10815 [=========================>....] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.0305 - acc: 0.9909

Comment: The base case: Train on 10815 samples, validate on 4636 samples
Epoch 1/10
 8576/10815 [======================>.......] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.0277 - acc: 0.1754

Comment: Keras               2.2.4
tensorboard         1.12.2     
tensorflow          1.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a custom binary cross-entropy loss, you should also specify the right accuracy metric. This is because if you use Keras' binary cross-entropy, then Keras will automatically adjust which accuracy metric to use (between binary and categorical accuracy).

This doesn't happen if you use a custom loss, and then Keras will default to categorical accuracy, which is actually wrong, producing incorrect accuracy values. For example:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```